# Julia mode in MacOS

Tags: debugging, osx

I updated my macOS from Big Sur to Monterey and found that my julia command does not work. Specifically, I use the following `init.el`. So far, I could send line using `C-return` but, now I got a message `<C-return> is undefined`. Also, hit `C-c C-c`, `C-c C-c is undefined`. How do I manage this?

```lisp
(use-package julia-mode
  :config
  (setq inferior-julia-program-name
    "/Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia")
  (add-hook 'ess-julia-mode-hook
            (lambda()
                  (define-key
                    ess-julia-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'julia-latexsub-or-indent))))
```

Comment: What version of emacs are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 27.2.

Comment: FYI I am using the [jupyter](https://melpa.org/#/jupyter) package and it seems to be working great (images inline, typing unicode with \ syntax works). I would recommend it (although the ess package might be working great also, but I have no experience with that). [This post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/jupyter-integration-with-emacs/21496/5?u=dalanicolai) might be useful if you would like to use jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

In July 2021, the `julia-mode` folks removed their code to communicate with the Julia REPL (known as an inferior process in Emacs terminology), and recommend using a third party package. This is all discussed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-emacs/issues/109).

Based on your hook, I'd assume you're trying to use ESS with Julia. If that's the case this is all I need to get my Julia code buffer working with the Julia REPL.

```lisp
;; ESS+Julia
(use-package julia-mode
  :ensure t)
(use-package ess
  :ensure t
  :init (require 'ess-site)
  :config
  (when (string= system-type "darwin")
    (setq inferior-julia-program
          "/Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"))
  (setq inferior-julia-args "--color=yes")
  (require 'ess-julia))
```

Note that `inferior-julia-program-name` is deprecated in favor of `inferior-julia-program`. Be sure to configure `ess` after `julia-mode`, or [add an `:after` clause](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#loading-packages-in-sequence) to the `ess` form.

If you're not using ESS with Julia, try one of the other packages listed in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-emacs/issues/109).

Comment: Also make sure your Julia repl is working on its own. There's no arm build of Julia for M1 macs yet, and if you've disabled Rosetta it's not going to work :)